# If Statement Inside $.each(data, function(key, value)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

Hi I am new here stackoverflow, please help me with my current problem, I have a problem using returning of data inside datatable. There's no problem on my console/alert the result is there but it always has "undefined" string beside the actual output.

undefinedFredick Martin //This is the sample output inside my datatable I just need "Fredick Martin"

So I need to remove the word "undefined", what I am doing is adding "IF STATEMENT" inside my for loop, and it's driving me crazy that I cannot get the right syntax for it

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("dist/js/results.json", function(data){ 
   var events_data = '';
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    $("#example1").DataTable().row.add([   
      value.EventEndDate,
      ((JV_Ajax(value.JVId) != "undefined") ? 'sample' + JV_Ajax(value.JVId) : ''), // My problem here on If statement
      value.Product,
      value.price_point,
      ]).draw();
  });
 });
});
```

```
((JV_Ajax(value.JVId) != 'Undefined') ? JV_Ajax(value.JVId) : '<span id="JV'+value.JVId+'"></span>'),
```

I added this If statement and It automatically alerted an error showing

"DataTables warning: table id=example1 - Requested unknown parameter '5' for row 183, column 5..."

As you can see at the top, I have AJAX function

```
<script>
function JV_Ajax(JVIds) {

 $.ajax({
  url: 'php/ajax_getJV.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    'JVId': JVIds
  },
  success: function(response) {

   console.log("Error: ", response);
   document.getElementById("JV"+JVIds).innerHTML = response;

 },  
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert("Error: " + thrownError);
}
});

}
</script>
```

ajax_getJV.php in my ajax

```
<?php 

require_once('Requestor.php');
$requestor = new Requestor;
echo $requestor->fetch_single("jvinfo","JVId",$_GET["JVId"]);

?>
```

Please let me know if you have need anything about my question, thank you!

P.S 
I am displaying already the actual Output, I just need to remove the word "Undefined" beside it. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Update Instead of

```
 ((JV_Ajax(value.JVId) != "undefined") ? 'sample' + JV_Ajax(value.JVId) : ''),
```

I modified it to

```
((typeof(JV_Ajax(value.JVId)) !== "undefined" && JV_Ajax(value.JVId) !== null) ? JV_Ajax(value.JVId) : '<span id="JV'+value.JVId+'"></span>'),
```

It removes now the Undefined but the other string that has duplicate didn't know show in the row